# AndroidStudioのエミュレーターでアプリを実行できない

Tags: android, android-studio

Windows8上のAndroidStudioでアプリ開発をしていたのですが、
先日パソコンのファイル整理をして以来、
AndroidStudioのエミュレーターでアプリを実行できなくなってしまいました。

状況としては、
エミュレーターを立ち上げる（普通に立ち上がりますし、アイコン一覧からアプリのプロジェクトをクリックすればそのアプリが実行されます）
→AndroidStudioの実行ボタン（◀）を押すが、何も起こらず、
実行ボタンは押されたまま

という感じです。エラーも出ていません。

AndroidSDKやJDK等はProjectStructureで示されている場所にありました。 
また、SDK Managerを確認しましたが、必要と思われるものはすべて入っていました。

どうすれば、◀ボタンを押したときにAndroidStudioで開いているプロジェクトのアプリが
実行されるでしょうか？
何か解決策等ありましたら教えていただきたいです。

---

追記

Target Deviceを確認したところ、
エミュレーターの名前が赤文字になっていたので、これも関係しているかもしれません。

[image: エミュレーターのエラー]

Answer (score 0):

windows/linux/Macよっても変わってくると思うので、それだけではなんとも。
ファイル整理をしたとの事なので、AndroidSDKなどのフォルダを移動していないか確認してみては？

Comment: すみません、windows8です。
androidSDKやJDK等はProjectStructureで示されている場所にありました。
何かたくさんバージョンがあったものを、１つ以外削除してしまったかもしれません。

Comment: SDK Managerでインストールできていないものが無いかどうか確認して、よくわからないようだったらデータを退避して再インストールしてみては。

Comment: SDK Managerを確認しましたが、必要と思われるものはすべて入っていました。
もしかしたらファイル整理は関係なく、
android studio上での設定をどこか変えてしまって起こったのかもしれません。

質問文に追記で示した部分もチェックしていただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 0):

windows 8のPro?でよいですか？またCPUのアーキテクチャわかりますか？
一部の仮想端末使うためにはHyper Vが必須で、いわゆるHomeではHyper V使えないとかいろいろ制約あります。またIntel 系のプロセッサならまだ楽ですが、AMD系を使っている場合、最悪、純粋エミュレータ（激遅）を使わなくてはいけないという。。。